# How do I embed a processing sketch on my webpage using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing

I have a processing sketch called `test.pde` which is in the same folder as my `index.html` web document. I also have a file called `processing.min.js` in that folder. I am trying to make it so that my processing sketch appears on my website.

Here is my code right now, but it just makes the resulting website blank:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Yaxlat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="websitestyle.css">
        <script src="processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas data-processing-sources="test.pde"></canvas> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but maybe because youre not specifying the size of the canvas?

try something like

`<canvas width="640" height="360"></canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

Im also trying to put a Processing sketch onto a webpage.

I've found a way to put the code straight into a HTML-file.
And it even works when I open the local file from my computer in a browser.

Try replacing your code in here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mouse2D \ Examples \ Processing.org</title>

    <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script -->
    <script src="processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <!-- script src="http://processing.org/javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.touch.js" type ="!text/javascript"></script -->
</head>

<body>
    <label>once</label>
    <br>
    <div class="proc">
    <script type="application/processing"> 
    void setup() 
    {
      size(640, 360);
      noStroke();
      rectMode(CENTER);
    }

    void draw() 
    {   
      background(51); 
      fill(255, 204);
      rect(mouseX, height/2, mouseY/2+10, mouseY/2+10);
      fill(255, 204);
      int inverseX = width-mouseX;
      int inverseY = height-mouseY;
      rect(inverseX, height/2, (inverseY/2)+10, (inverseY/2)+10);
    }

    </script>
    <canvas width="640" height="360"></canvas>
    <div>this is below the canvas</div>


</body>
```

My problem is, that although this works locally, it jsut gives me a blank canvas on my Google App Engine.
Hope this helps you!